# Django Installed Apps - path full/partial

Tags: django

I was creating this django project and it has a class named "jobs". Now how do i add this "jobs" app in my setting.py. Some say we need to add full path like

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'jobs.apps.JobsConfig'
]
```

and some say just add the app name like

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'jobs'
]
```

can anyone tell me which is correct please?

Comment: You just need to add the app name in settings file.

Comment: Update your question with the project structure as your question is confusing. First you say `jobs` is a class inside project then you say its an app. What is it actually ?